# GCP Dataproc - Failed to construct kafka consumer, Failed to load SSL keystore dataproc.jks of type JKS

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to run a Structured Streaming program on GCP Dataproc, which accesses the data from Kafka and prints it.

Access to Kafka is using SSL, and the truststore and keystore files are stored in buckets.
I'm using Google Storage API to access the bucket, and store the file in the current working directory. The truststore and keystores are passed onto the Kafka Consumer/Producer.
However - i'm getting an error

Command :

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark /Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/gcp/DataProc/StructuredStreaming_Kafka_GCP-Batch-feb2-v2.py  --cluster dataproc-ss-poc  --properties spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 --region us-central1
```

Code is shown below :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('StructuredStreaming_VersaSase').getOrCreate()

kafkaBrokers='<broker-ip>:9094'
topic = "versa-sase"
security_protocol="SSL"

# Google Storage API to access the keys in the buckets
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('ssl-certs-karan')

blob_ssl_truststore = bucket.get_blob('cap12.jks')
ssl_truststore_location = '{}/{}'.format(os.getcwd(), blob_ssl_truststore.name) 
blob_ssl_truststore.download_to_filename(ssl_truststore_location)

ssl_truststore_password="<ssl_truststore_password>"

blob_ssl_keystore = bucket.get_blob('dataproc-versa-sase-p12-1.jks')
ssl_keystore_location = '{}/{}'.format(os.getcwd(), blob_ssl_keystore.name) 
blob_ssl_keystore.download_to_filename(ssl_keystore_location)


ssl_keystore_password="<ssl_keystore_password>"
consumerGroupId = "versa-sase-grp"
checkpoint = "gs://ss-checkpoint/"

print(" SPARK.SPARKCONTEXT -> ", spark.sparkContext)


df = spark.read.format('kafka')\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers)\
    .option("kafka.security.protocol","SSL") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location",ssl_truststore_location) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password",ssl_truststore_password) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location)\
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password)\
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .option("kafka.group.id", consumerGroupId)\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

   print(" df -> ", df)
   query = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(key AS STRING)", "topic", "timestamp") \
    .write \
    .format("console") \
    .option("numRows",100)\
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint) \
    .option("outputMode", "complete")\
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .save("output")
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/3e7304f8e27d4436a2f382280cebe7c5/StructuredStreaming_Kafka_GCP-Batch-feb2-v2.py", line 83, in <module>
    query = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(key AS STRING)", "topic", "timestamp") \
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1109, in save
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError22/02/02 23:11:08 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: IPC Client (1416219052) connection to dataproc-ss-poc-m/10.128.0.78:8030 from root sending #171 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationMasterProtocolPB.allocate
22/02/02 23:11:08 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: IPC Client (1416219052) connection to dataproc-ss-poc-m/10.128.0.78:8030 from root got value #171
22/02/02 23:11:08 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: allocate took 2ms
: An error occurred while calling o84.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (dataproc-ss-poc-w-0.c.versa-kafka-poc.internal executor 1): org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:665)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:613)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumer.createConsumer(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$ObjectFactory.create(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$ObjectFactory.create(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:201)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BaseKeyedPooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BaseKeyedPooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:342)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool.borrowObject(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.retrieveConsumer(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.getOrRetrieveConsumer(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.$anonfun$getAvailableOffsetRange$1(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.runUninterruptiblyIfPossible(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.getAvailableOffsetRange(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD.resolveRange(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD.compute(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
...

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /tmp/3e7304f8e27d4436a2f382280cebe7c5/dataproc-versa-sase-p12-1.jks of type JKS
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:377)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.<init>(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.createKeystore(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:299)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.configure(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.instantiateSslEngineFactory(SslFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:737)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/3e7304f8e27d4436a2f382280cebe7c5/dataproc-versa-sase-p12-1.jks
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:370)
```

From my mac, I'm using PKCS files (.p12) and am able to access the Kafka cluster in SSL mode. However, in Dataproc - it seems the expected file format is JKS.

here is the command i used to convert .p12 file to JKS format:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore dataproc-versa-sase.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias versa-sase-user -destkeystore dataproc-versa-sase-p12-1.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass <password> -destalias versa-sase-user
```

What needs to be done to fix this ?
it seems the JKS file is not accessible to the Spark program ?

tia!

Comment: `os.getcwd()` gets evaluated on the driver, not the executors where the file locations are actually used. You should try using `--files` to send the certs to the the executors. Then, you'll want to modify the path in the config to pickup from the executor directory. You'll also probably want to download the files via a shell script and checking their existence before submitting rather than constantly downloading as part of the driver

Comment: @OneCricketeer - thnx, how do i access the files (passed as parameters to --files), and pass the same to KafkaComsumer ?  pls note - I checked the documentation, and don't see it mentioned clearly

Comment: @KaranAlang you can set in the sparkconf most like since you are using dataproc to submit I am thinking.

Comment: `spark.files` is the config option string. You access files relative to the executor using `#`. For example, `spark.files=/tmp/foo/data/data.txt` from the driver should be able to refer to `#data.txt` in the executor. It should be possible to do whole folders too like setting `/tmp/foo` you'd access `#data/data.txt`, I think... It's actually a Hadoop specific thing, but I remember seeing it somewhere in the Spark docs

Comment: @OneCricketeer - thnx, i was able to use --files and pass the certs, and access the certs on the worker nodes, this also works if this is run in cluster mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per note from @OneCricketer, i was able to get this working by using `--files <gs://cert1>,<gs://cert2>`.
Also, this works when using the cluster mode.

ClusterMode command

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark /Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/gcp/DataProc/StructuredStreaming_Kafka_GCP-Batch-feb2-v2.py  --cluster dataproc-ss-poc  --properties spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,spark.submit.deployMode=cluster --region us-central1
```

Client Mode :

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark /Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/gcp/DataProc/StructuredStreaming_Kafka_GCP-Batch-feb2-v2.py  --cluster dataproc-ss-poc  --properties spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 --region us-central1
```

Accessing the certs in the Driver:

```
# access using the cert name
ssl_truststore_location="ca.p12"
ssl_keystore_location="dataproc-versa-sase.p12"

df_stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", ssl_truststore_location) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", ssl_truststore_password) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers)\
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .option("kafka.group.id", consumerGroupId)\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10) \
    .load()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add the following option if you want to use jks

```
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.type", "JKS")
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "JKS")
```

Also this will work with PKCS12 by the way

```
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.type", "PKCS12")
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12")
```

Like someone mention earlier you can check if it is jdk compatibility issue doing something like so:

```
keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore kafka-client-jdk8-truststore.p12
```

If you receive a  message displaying keystore you are in the clear, but if you  receive a message saying the Identifier can’t be found that means difference in jdks.

Comment: i added this, now i get the error  ```Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /tmp/65faa8c43eef4ebf8df986b92558a861/dataproc-versa-sase.p12 of type PKCS12```

Comment: are you trying to jks or pkcs12 @KaranAlang

Comment: i'm using PKCS now (after adding the options you mentioned), since the PKCS files work fine when i run from my local m/c .. however, getting the error mentioned above ie. failed to load SSL keystore of type PKCS12

Comment: Try with jks cause your cert script is convert pksc12 to jks

Comment: @user12398097 - same error with jks as well